# How can I implement an algorithm for a matrix where each cell can have one of two values, with hints

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Firstly, sorry for the vagueness of the title.

I don't know if there is a name for this sort of algorithm.

I am interested in finding out how this scenario could be implemented.

Say I have a matrix (columns and rows) where each "cell" can have one of two values ("on" and "off").

Each cell's "background" should also display a number that tells how many of the adjacent cells are "on".

For example, if every cell should be "on":

| A | B | C |  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 6 | 4 | --> | on | on | on |
| 6 | 9 | 6 |  | on | on | on |
| 4 | 6 | 4 |  | on | on | on |

This is pretty simple to implement. The question is: **what's the minimal amount of tips I can have, and how can I implement this?**

In this same example, it would be enough to have:

| A | B | C |  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | --> | on | on | on |
|  | 9 |  |  | on | on | on |
|  |  |  |  | on | on | on |

It can get trickier:

| A | B | C |  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | --> | on | ? | off |
| 4 |  | 1 |  | on | ? | off |
|  |  |  |  | on | ? | off |

In this last example, the matrix would be larger and have other hints that later on would help determine the remaining cells.

So how can this be achieved?

Comment: This looks pretty much line "mine sweeper" the game. Look it up and also tell me what you found because I'm also interested in the answer :D

Comment: @user1984 sure thing. Mine sweeper is somewhat different. The numbers always show the adjacent mine count. I am more interested in the "advanced" version where you have to take into account other numbers as well and by exclusion arrive at the right answer.

Comment: This is like an inverse-sudoku/inverse constraint satisfaction problem. You're given the completed grid (the full arrangement of on/off) and you have to find the minimum number of clues. In the literature, this is usually called the `Smallest Critical Set`, and has been studied for things like Latin squares. For sudoku, they solved the Smallest Critical Set problem by transforming it into a hitting set formulation: see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0749), whose techniques should probably also work on your problem. It's still exponential time, but much better than brute force.

Comment: @kcsquared thanks! I am gonna read it. Just to clarify it, I am interested in creating this matrices, not solving them. (I want to create them for other people to solve it manually)